# OperationalError at / could not connect to server:

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sockets, unix

My Django App is showing  the following error "OperationalError at /  could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the server running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?" Why?

Comment: Your postgres is down

Comment: sudo service postgresql (re)start

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232137/github-action-docker-database-migration-fail