# github action docker database migration fail

Tags: docker, database-migration, digital-ocean, github-actions

I am trying to build CI/CD environment using github action.

Below script helps me to build the docker image, but returning an error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "db-postgresql-nyc1.b.db.ondigitalocean.com" (157.230.224.47) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 23052?
```

localhost can successfully migrate the database without any errors. However, when I use github action, it fails.

Maybe I should try manipulating firewalls from digital ocean or github? If you have any suggestion, please let me know.

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: docker login
      env:
        DOCKER_ID: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
        DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }} 
      run: |
        docker login -u $DOCKER_ID -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
    - name: docker build
      run: |
        docker rmi --force "dummy/dummy-community:latest"
        docker build -t polls . 
    - name: docker migrate
      run: |
        docker run --env-file env polls sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate"
    - name: docker tag image
      run: |
        docker tag polls:latest dummy/dummy-community:latest
    - name: docker push
      run: |
        docker push dummy/dummy-community:latest
    - name: kubectl deploy
      run: |
        kubectl delete pods polls-app
        kubectl get deploy polls-app
```

Answer (score 0):

There is often a race condition between starting up Postgres and Django.  When the Postgres container starts up, the container is listed as started, but underneath the hood, the actual database server process is still starting up.  When the Django container starts up, it immediately tries to connect to the database but fails.

Typically, one might take one of two courses of action:

1. Use a smaller Postgres image.  With less stuff to work with, the database server process starts up faster.  Sometimes the `postgres:12-alpine` (or the `<version>-alpine` image that matches your version requirement) will spin up postgres fast enough so that Django can access it by the time it starts up.  But still, it's a race to the finish, and you can encounter the same error
2. Write a polling script to confirm that Postgres is up and taking queries before moving on to `makemigrations`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
  # Check if database is taking queries
  psql -Atc "SELECT 1" -p <port> -U <user> <database>
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "Database is not started, waiting and trying again
  sleep 0.5 # or however long you want
done

# broke out of the while loop, proceed to migration
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Of course, the above code snippet is a rudimentary check -- you may want to write something a bit more robust.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am wondering if a real world application is made it like this process.

Comment: As you suggested, I was able to implement github action to wait for the database to run. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/creating-postgresql-service-containers  I believe the digital ocean db is blocking github action. Is there any other suggestion?